Can not expand the width of the list tile
I have created two pages for Transactions and Category, in Category page there is a Custom Tab Bar (Income and Expense). As usual when the value changes the list change along with it.
The problem I am facing is the list of Income or Expense is not taking the full width of the page.

class NewCustomTabBar extends StatefulWidget {
  const NewCustomTabBar({super.key});

  @override
  _NewCustomTabBarState createState() => _NewCustomTabBarState();
}

class _NewCustomTabBarState extends State<NewCustomTabBar>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late TabController _tabController;
  String _selectedSegment = 'income';

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _tabController = TabController(length: 2, vsync: this);
    _tabController.addListener(() {
      setState(() {
        _selectedSegment = _tabController.index == 0 ? 'income' : 'expense';
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _tabController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void _onSegmentChanged(String value) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedSegment = value;
      _tabController.index = value == 'income' ? 0 : 1;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        CustomSlidingSegmentedControl<String>(
          height: 50,
          initialValue: _selectedSegment,
          children: const {
            'income': Text(
              'Income',
              style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.black,
                  fontSize: 18,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
            ),
            'expense': Text(
              'Expense',
              style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.black,
                  fontSize: 18,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
            ),
          },
          onValueChanged: _onSegmentChanged,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.grey[300],
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
            boxShadow: [
              BoxShadow(
                color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.1),
                blurRadius: 8,
              ),
            ],
          ),
          thumbDecoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.green,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6),
          ),
          duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
          curve: Curves.easeInToLinear,
        ),
       `Expanded(
          child: TabBarView(controller: _tabController, children: const [
            IncomeCategoryList(),
            ExpenseCategoryList(),
          ])`
        )
      ]
    );
  }
}

Then I have tried the fixedwidth widget in the Custom Tab Bar Widget
fixedWidth: 110
But the fixed Width widget only changes the width of the Tab Bar.

Try wrapping the first Column with:
    SizedBox(
      width: double.infinite,
      ....

)

Be cause your first column not take full width size of page

Tried it, the problem is, (I said the List took the same width as Tab Bar, that's not the case. I have edited the question) I can change the width of the Tab Bar, but the lists are the same as in the picture.

The problem was I had a padding in the Category Screen, that was the reason for the list tile to behave that way:
    class _CategoryScreenState extends State<CategoryScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // return Padding(
    //   padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 84, vertical: 20),
    //   child: Column(
    //     children: [
    //       //CustomTabBar(),
    //     ],
    //   ),
    // );
    return const Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20),
      child: NewCustomTabBar(),
    );
  }
}

As you can see I had horizontal padding: 84 for the Column, I have commented the wrong code and replaced it. My bad!
